# Is a language which is your second but currently main "adopted" or "adoptive"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

If an ESL person who is mainly English-speaking now is referring to his relationship with the English language, is English their *adopted* or *adoptive* main language? (Or are neither of the words correct in this context in the first place?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Adoptive* refers to the thing doing the adopting, so you would be the language's *adoptive user*.

*Adopted* refers to the thing that is adopted, it is your *adopted language*.

I think it is fine to use *adopted* in this sense. It implies that you have taken the language on as if it were your own.

Comment: It's true *adopted* is far more common for this context, but I don't see anything wrong with *adoptive* - it's a somewhat "metaphoric" usage either way round, so it's not unreasonable for the **mother tongue** to "adopt" non-native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ...yes, except that 'adoptive langauge' is [much rarer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adopted+language%2C+adoptive+language&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than 'adopted language' and interestingly almost nonexistent in [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adopted+language%2Cadoptive+language&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3).

Comment: Yes, as I said, *adopted* is far more common. I'm just saying that constructions like *my adoptive homeland* don't seem unreasonable to me. I think it's more a matter of "majority" rather than "correct" usage.